# In Acumatica I'm getting error while publishing the customization

Tags: asp.net, xml, api, acumatica, acumatica-kb

Method PX.CS.Contracts.Interfaces.IAddressBase GetToAddress(PX.Objects.AR.ARInvoice, System.Func`2[PX.Objects.AR.ARInvoice,PX.CS.Contracts.Interfaces.IAddressBase]) in graph extension is marked as [PXOverride], but the original method with such name has not been found in PXGraph
Method PX.CS.Contracts.Interfaces.IAddressBase GetToAddress(PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder, System.Func`2[PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder,PX.CS.Contracts.Interfaces.IAddressBase]) in graph extension is marked as [PXOverride], but the original method with such name has not been found in PXGraph

Comment: please format your code properly so that it is easily readable. You'll likely get an answer sooner this way

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you copy the whole method as is, and then add the PXOverride above, missing a parameter or spelling will cause the system to not pick up the original method